# How do I delete a file using the Terminal from my Trash in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sudo, trash

From a previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/31608/top-sites-managing-default-top-sites-in-safari) I have applied following command to my file.

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg TopSites.plist
sudo chmod 444 TopSites.plist
```

Now that the file is locked, I don't know how to remove it.

I currently have the file in my trash.

What does `sudo` do? And where can I find more info about it?
Where is the Trash stored in Mac OS X?
How do I delete this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` executes a command as another user. By default (as in this case) the user is the superuser root, which can do almost anything. The trash is located in `~/.Trash`. You can delete the entire trash by running:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Answer (score 4):

**sudo**

`sudo` stands for super user do, you can find more about it by using `man sudo` in the Terminal. The crux is that you can perform a command temporarily as root meaning you have complete privileges - when you are asked for your password in applications to do certain actions (eg. installing) it's the GUI equivalent of using sudo.

**Trash location**

Your Trash for your startup drive can be found at `~/.Trash/`, whereas for external hard drives it can be found at `/Volumes/NAME_OF_EXTERNAL/.Trashes/USER_ID/` where USER_ID is your  user id.

**Deleting Files**

You have a couple options to delete the file: If you hold <kbd>Option</kbd> when you empty the Trash you can force empty the trash that will delete locked files like yours.

Alternatively you can use the Terminal to run the `rm` command (stands for remove). The `rm` command will delete the file (No trash, it's just gone so be careful using it). So for example `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` will erase every file in your trash. If you ran `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` it would do it with superuser privileges.

The flags in the `rm` command stand for recursively (`-r`) and force (`-f`). You can find more about `rm` by running `man rm`.

Answer (score 2):

You can force the removal by holding down the Option key while emptying the trash.

**sudo** allows you to run commands as another user.  If no user is specified, root is used.

**chflags** changes file or folder "flags".  The *-R* switch makes the command recursive, i.e. it will apply to all files in all subfolders. **uchg** makes the file immutable, **nouchg** clears the immutable flag.

**chmod** changes a file or folder's permissions.  444 is the octal permissions bitmask of a file that is read-only by everybody, including the owner. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/20457/modification-of-files-with-777-permissions-but-not-with-755-permissions) for an explanation of octal masks and chmod.

Typing **man *'command name'*** in a terminal will give you a complete description of all these commands.

Comment: that's not really a terminal way of doing things...

Comment: @alexus - Richard is right. Any how I wanted to empty trash. You both are right. Thanks a lot for helping me.